# Skin for grid not work in ie8+?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have skin file for grid as below:

```
   <asp:GridView runat="server"  RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="1"
   GridLines="None" 
   Width="100%" >
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="tabletopbg_White" HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
   <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="paging" />
   <EmptyDataRowStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
   <RowStyle CssClass="alt_1" />
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt_2" />
   <FooterStyle CssClass="paging" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
   </asp:GridView>
```

Header alignment left works well in all browser except IE.
What is the solution?

Comment: Is tabletopbg_White accessible?

Comment: Yes, Amitbhai and works well in other browsers.

Comment: In IE check there CSS file is available or not, IE have some limitation if there  is more than 30 files then It will remove.

Comment: How the `tabletopbg_White` css is defined ? This is not called skin. Also this very small issues can be solved only if you have the page live and use the browser tools to see what's going wrong. Or at least the rendered table with the full css that is used for that table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have reached the limit of `31 CSS files` and  tags that IE can handle. In this case, please add a RadStyleSheetManager control to the page and it will combine the embedded stylesheets into one.

**Refer:**

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager.html

Comment: Where did you see 31 css files on that question ?

Comment: Its not mentioned in the question, but can be in the answer. When 31 CSS files limit is crossed, this kind of things may happen.

Comment: Then maybe you can answer the same on all the `css` tagged questions ? Where did say that is use Rad controls ? He can not use the RadStyleSheetManager to combine the styles, because simple is not use Rad Controls. Also this is not the case because is only one small issue ask - the align. Is not break the full schema.

Comment: why??? all the CSS taged questions are related to gridview skin not working for IE 8? ?

Comment: What I say you is, that your answer to a non existing situation, make it general, and as general can not be a real solution to anything. And in this case did not have 31 css files.